# Atribuição de array em variável

Tags: php, array, variáveis

Existe uma forma correta de se fazer este trecho de código destacado?

```
$numeros = range(0, 9);
shuffle($numeros);
$id = array_slice($numeros, 1, 9);

$mult = $id[0].$id[1].$id[2].$id[3].$id[4].$id[5].$id[6].$id[7].$id[8];

echo $mult;
```

ou seja, minha intenção é transformar um *array* em uma variável simples para utilização posterior, no caso este trecho

```
$mult = $id[0].$id[1].$id[2].$id[3].$id[4].$id[5].$id[6].$id[7].$id[8];
```

poderia ser feito de uma outra forma mais profissional?

Comment: O que você chama de forma mais profissional? Você quer fazer sem repetir a variável 9 vezes?

Comment: exatamente @bigown , eu queria saber se tem como simplesmente não repetir 9 vezes a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que é isto que você quer:

```
$numeros = range(0, 9);
shuffle($numeros);
$id = array_slice($numeros, 1, 9);
$mult = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    $mult .= $id[$i];
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ml1yR0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ShuffleArray). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/ShuffeArray.php).

Desta forma você está fazendo o a variável repetir noves vezes de forma automática. Você está criando um laço de repetição. Então ali no `for`você está contando de 0 até 9, incrementando um por um, então em cada passada pelo laço ele pega um índice diferente do `array` conforme a variável contadora do laço. Cada passem ele vai concatenando o novo elemento do *array* à variável que receberá o resultado final.

O resultado é exatamente o mesmo que o que você fez e esta forma chama-se [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Documentação do [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) e do [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) para mais referências e estudo.

Comment: exatamente isso, muito obrigado, no caso o trabalho está sendo feito no `$mult .=` ?

Comment: Na verdade nas 4 últimas linhas. É um todo, não dá para analisar só uma linha.

Comment: o .= estaria concatenando o valor atual com o novo valor do proximo laço, exato? sem o . ele iria apagar o atual e trocar para o novo?

Comment: Ele não apaga, ele concatena, e concatenar e adicionar um texto a outro já existe. Não é substituir, é adicionar. Então ele vai acumulando um atrás do outro. Se você mudar a expressão `$i < 9` para um número menor, pode começar do 1 e ver o que acontece. Aí você vai subindo até chegar no 9. Para visualizar melhor você pode colocar uma linha com `echo $mult. "\n";` dentro do laço para ver como ele vai evoluindo em cada passada.

Comment: sim, tentei mas mandou aguardar cerca de 5 minutos, mas então, foi o que mencionei, o .= o ponto faz o trabalho de concatenar, o resto eu ja sabia, só nao percebi que poderia por um . ponto antes do = igual para funcionar

Comment: Isto chama-se [operador de atribuição composto](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php). É o mesmo que fazer `$mult = $mult . $id[$i];`. O rray deu uma outra forma de fazer. EU pensei nela mas evitei porque percebi que você está aprendendo, achei melhor te ensinar o básico antes de pegar tudo mastigado. Acho que você deve entender o que está fazendo, como chegar no resultado. A função implode internamente funciona de forma muito semelhante ao que eu postei para você.

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma de converter um array para uma string utilizar [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), o primeiro argumento é o array a ser convertido, o segundo seria delimitador que ficaria entre os itens do array, nesse caso pode usar nada(`''`) assim a string gerada será um número de 10 digitos.

```
<?php
$numeros = range(0, 9);
$str_numero = implode($numeros, '');
echo $str_numero;
```

[phpfiddle - exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rti1-dgby)

Comment: realmente funcionou muito bem, implementando o shuffle ele ficou completo `  $rand_rules = range(0, 9);
 shuffle($rand_rules);
 $rand_rules = array_slice($rand_rules, 1, 9);
 $str_numero = implode($rand_rules, "");
 echo $str_numero."\n"; `

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar a função `serialize()` e a função `unserialize()`, entre outras. (JSON por exemplo)

[Link para a documentação da função `serialize`](http://php.net/serialize)

[Link para a documentação da função `unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php)

---

PS: sei que não é o caso descrito, fica apenas como uma alternativa mais abrangente.

Comment: -1? Se importa de explicar o porque?